# How to prove that the Fourier expansion converges absolutely and uniformly in an interval?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Given $ (2\cos\frac{\theta}{2})^\alpha \cos\frac{\alpha \theta}{2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\n\\ \end{pmatrix} \cos n\theta$, where $\alpha>0$ is real, how to prove that this Fourier expansion converges absolutely and uniformly in the interval $[0,2\pi] $?

Consider the binomial series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\n\\ \end{pmatrix}z^n$$
where  $$ \begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\n\\ \end{pmatrix} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(\alpha-n+1)}{n!} $$ is the generalized binomial coefficients with $\alpha$ can be a complex number.

According to the Abel's limit theorem below
[image]

The Fourier expansion is obtained by the following argument:

[image]
[image]

In addition, (17.43) is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure $\alpha$ is real? What if $\alpha=1/2$?

Comment: How do you define $(2\cos\frac{\theta}{2})^\alpha$ when $\pi<\theta<2\,\pi$?

Comment: @anderstood my friend, more background information have been supplied.

Comment: @Julián Aguirre, my friend, please review my question again and help me.

Comment: I think the interval should be $[-\pi,\pi]$, as indicated before (17.44).

Comment: The Fourier series are periodic with period $2\pi$.  They converge to 
the given functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$.  Indeed, if $\alpha$ is not an integer $\cos(\theta/2)^\alpha$ is not real for $\theta \in (\pi, 2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us (17.43), which says that the binomial series converges
absolutely and uniformly on the unit circle.  That's the main point, I think.  It might go something like this:

Using the reflection formula for the Gamma function

$${\alpha \choose n} = \dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{n!\; \Gamma(\alpha - n + 1)} =  \dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\; \Gamma(n-\alpha)\sin((n-\alpha) \pi)}{\pi n!}$$

Now for $n > \alpha$, $$0 < \dfrac{\Gamma(n+1-\alpha)}{(n+1)!} = \dfrac{n-\alpha}{n+1} \dfrac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{n!} $$

For $n$ sufficiently large, we have $$\dfrac{n-\alpha}{n+1} < \dfrac{(n+1)^{-1-\alpha}}{n^{-1-\alpha}}$$
so that we obtain
$$ \left| {\alpha \choose n}\right| < C(\alpha) n^{-1-\alpha}$$
for some $C\alpha)$.  Since $\sum_{n} n^{-1-\alpha}$ converges, these series converge absolutely and uniformly.

Comment: Yes, (17.43) is proved similarly in the textbook. However, my question is about the convergence interval of $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\n\\ \end{pmatrix} \cos n\theta $. Why it is  $[0,2\pi]$. Please help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: The convergence interval is not $[0,2\pi]$.  This converges for all real $\theta$, because $|\cos(n\theta)| \le 1$.

Comment: Do you mean $[0,2\pi]$ is a misprint and it should be replaced by $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: As you explained, the Fourier expansions converge for all real $\theta$, but they converge to the given functions (only) on $[-\pi,\pi]$.